# Drupal visualization with highcharts, how to set size

Tags: 7, charts

I'm trying to write a module that is implemnting a block containing a pie chart. The pie chart is implemented using [visualization](https://www.drupal.org/project/visualization) together with highchats.

It displays the pie chart at the moment but it is to big for my site. Does anyone know how to set the overall chart size?

I downloaded visualization three days ago but I've not been able to patch the module with visualization-more_control-1809850-13.patch (see https://www.drupal.org/node/1809850) unfortunately..

Here is the option array I use in my module.

```
  $options_pie = array(
           'title' => t(''),
           'fields' => array(
                     'antal' => array(
                              'label' => t('Amount'),
                              'enabled' => TRUE,
                              ),
                     ),
           'xAxis' => array(
                    'labelField' => 'certificate',
                    ),
           'data' => $data,
           'type' => 'pie',
           );
```